# Unity HTML5 error : Encoding 1252 data could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, html, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm on Mac, and I have the pb of the "Codepage 1252 not supported" when executing my little application in Google Chrome. I'm using the **Unity 2017 June beta** in order to integrate **GeometryGymIFC** lib which is coded for **.NET 4.6**, now enable (theoretically) in this last Unity version.

Unfortunately, putting **I18N.dll and I18N.West.dll** in Assets does not resolve the pb for WebGL target.

**Note** : there are many "unity" DLL folders :

- unity
- unity_aot
- unity_web <=== this one **does not** contain I18N.dll and I18N.West.dll
  :(

Maybe I have to choose a particular version of I18N.dll and I18N.West.dll ?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution :**

1) Put

```
I18N.dll 
I18N.West.dll
```

from

```
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Mono/lib/mono/unity
```

into Assets.

2) Then, add "link.xml" in Assets too, with this content :

```
<linker>
<assembly fullname="I18N" preserve="all"/>
<assembly fullname="I18N.West" preserve="all"/>
<assembly fullname="GeometryGymIFC" preserve="all"/>
</linker>
```

It works !