# Unsupported encoding while parsing excel

Tags: c#, android, excel, unity-game-engine, exceldatareader

I use the following code to open an `Excel` file using `ExcelDataReader`.

```
excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream, new ExcelReaderConfiguration()
            {
                FallbackEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,

                LeaveOpen = false,

                AnalyzeInitialCsvRows = 0,
            });
```

The issue is that Im getting the following error,

> Encoding 1252 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct
>   international codeset assembly installed and enabled.

Based on other solutions, I have also included `i18N.dll` and `i18n.west.dll` files to my project but still, the issue is persisting.

Comment: Tried creating a folder named "DLL" in Assets folder? Try adding all the DLL's from ```Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity``` to that folder and try again. Also change the scripting backend from IL2CPP to Mono2x.

Comment: Yes I tried doing so but still Im facing the same issue :(

Comment: try this solution as well ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162955/unity-html5-error-encoding-1252-data-could-not-be-found```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
FallbackEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

My code:

```
ExcelReaderConfiguration conf = new ExcelReaderConfiguration();
conf.FallbackEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);


using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream, conf))
{
....
}
                {
```